# How to get methods from other project in the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have this structure:

```
-Main [solution]
       -MainApp [project]
           -Models [folder]
               -DbContext.cs
           -Controler  [folder]
               -TestControler.cs

       -MainAppRepository [project]
           -SomeClass.cs
```

This is my MVC application. I want to get access to fields from `DbContext.cs` in my `SomeClass.cs`, and to have access to methods from `SomeClass.cs` in `TestControler.cs`.
How can I do this? 
I've tried with `Add dependences` function, but without any result..

Comment: Isn't that a circular dependency?

Comment: I would highly recommend moving your `DbContext` out of both solutions, and into a third *Class Library* project.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, why should I do this? I know now that this is cause `circular dependency` situation, but I'm asking general - why should I move my `Models` and `DbContext` and `Repositories` to separate projects? And not to storage them in main project? I try to learn IoC and DI patterns and it is not understandable for me at all. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Did you import the namespace ("using MainApp") as well?